# hp laptop battery only shows 90% charge

Tags: windows-10-v1607

hello all I would like help when my laptop is fully charged the power light turns white that is normal but the battery icon on taskbar only shows up to about 90% then goes no further hope you can help thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the battery drain faster than normal? For how long have you been using the battery

Comment: fully charging can reduce battery life. best is to keep it between 30-85%. so maybe this is caused from a HP tool.